# PHPMyadmin does not show mysql error messages

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I installed phpMyAdmin on my site and it works. But when I mistype a query it does not show the mysql error message only the error code.

1064 -

I expect the following:

1064 - You have and error in your blah blah...

Without an error message it's difficult to know what's wrong.

In my php scripts I'm able to get the error message via mysql_error(). But myAdmin shows nothing.

I googled a lot but I didn't find anything useful.

How can I make it show the error messages?

Any ideas?

Comment: After you login to phpMyAdmin the bottom-right will have error messages that might help.  I have a the same issue on one of my servers and I have the following message: "Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.45 differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.48. This may cause unpredictable behavior."  It's something I haven't bothered with but would require a Library Update / MySQL Roll.

Comment: Belongs to sererfault but can take a look at here

http://serverfault.com/questions/12020/how-do-i-go-about-turning-on-mysql-error-messages

Comment: It's a fresh phpmyadmin install. I don't have any warning messages about differing versions. I saw that SF post but I think that guy had no mysql error messages at all. Please note in my php scripts I'm able to get the error message through mysql_error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the fact that you get "#1064 -" as output, I can find only two places in the phpMyAdmin 3.3.9.2 source where the error could be occurring. The first is in the call to `mysql_error` or `mysqli_error`, depending on which backend your installation is using. I see you said that `mysql_error` works fine; if the phpMyAdmin information page you get when first logging in indicates that mysqli is being used, you might want to check that too.

But if mysql_error works, it seems more likely that the problem is in phpMyAdmin's character set conversion function `PMA_DBI_convert_message` in libraries/database_interface.lib.php. You can confirm this easily enough by inserting `return $message;` at the very top of that function, bypassing everything else in there. If that makes it (more or less) work, you'd probably want to determine what `$server_language` and `$GLOBALS['charset']` are getting set to; see if the conversion is using `iconv`, `recode_string`, `libiconv`, or `mb_convert_encoding`; and then try to work out why whichever of those is failing to convert the error message properly.

Comment: My webhoster runs it's own myadmin installation so I can't access it's config. But I installed a pma on my website and this (return $message) hack worked fine on it. (anyway I don't mind the encoding of the errors as long as they are in English.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Server cannot correctly access LOCALE settings. It happens on chroot-ed / chjail-ed environments or poor configuration.

Based on @Anomie answer, I made a workaround.

**For phpmyadmin 4.4.3** change the Fallback setting in file `libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php`

```
 /* Fallback to CP1252 if we can not detect */
        $encoding = 'UTF-8';
```

**For some older versions**, edit file `libraries/database_interface.lib.php` and set 
`array $encodings => 'english'` value to `UTF-8` (~line 273),

```
'english'       => 'UTF-8', //'latin1',
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see :

> `$cfg['Error_Handler']['display']`
>   boolean
>
> Whether to display errors from PHP or not.
>
> `$cfg['Error_Handler']['gather']`
>   boolean
>
> Whether to gather errors from PHP or not.

[In the docs](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config) ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, which was solved by disabling the FireFox add-on uBlock (version: Origin 1.25.2) in my browser for phpmyadmin.