# my_udf_init not called

Tags: mysql, c, user-defined-functions

This is my first time trying to create an udf for mysql. The docs state that `my_func_init` gets called prior to executing the main function, yet in my environment this does not seem to happen.

```
long long charmatch(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error)
{
    return 42;
}

my_bool charmatch_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
    if (args->arg_count != 2)
    {
        strncpy(message, "charmatch() requires two arguments", 34);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        // was return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if(args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT)
    {
        strncpy(message, "argument 1 must be a string", 27);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        // was return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if(args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT)
    {
        strncpy(message, "argument 2 must be a string", 27);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        // was return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, I'm checking whether there are two arguments. In theory `SELECT CHARMATCH()` should return a message saying I must set two arguments, but it's not: it return 42.

Why doesn't it return the message?

**EDIT** Seems like the problem was in my return values for errors being 0 instead of 1. I fixed it and now calling `SELECT CHARMATCH()` with the wrong number of arguments returns an empty set. Why are the errors not being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always return EXIT_SUCCESS in charmatch_init(), but

> "The initialization function should return 0 if no error occurred and 1 otherwise. If an error occurs, xxx_init() should store a null-terminated error message in the message parameter. "

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-return-values.html

I guess that's why your error messages are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I changed my return values accordingly, but the error message is not displayed.

Comment: My second guess would be that it has something to do with strncpy(), with this function, destination will only be null-terminated if the length of the C string in source is less than number passed. Can you try to set length for strncpy() as MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE?

Comment: do you also know why mysql displays the error for my udf in cli, but not in a php script (phpMyAdmin for example)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735924/phpmyadmin-does-not-show-mysql-error-messages ?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too vague. It returns a perfectly valid response, albeit an empty one. There are no errors returned. No results are also not returned when I call `SELECT CHARMATCH(), foo.* FROM foo;`. It's getting late so I can't test this in any of my application, but I'm assuming they would break silently as well.