# phpMyAdmin truncates error messages

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I use phpMyAdmin to perform queries, any errors being returned are missing error descriptions. Error returned is just:

```
#1064 -
```

[image: phpMyAdmin missing error description]

... rather than the expected one:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...
```

My PHP code is returning MySQL error descriptions correctly using `mysql_error()`.

<sub>I spent 2 days searching for answers on Google and SO for a solution and could not find one. 
Therefore for future reference for myself and anyone else searching for the answer to this problem, I'll answer it here. If you have a better solution, please add your answer.</sub>

Comment: can u please send the query

Comment: @Madhav - The question is not about a specific query, it's about phpMyAdmin truncating error messages. (And he only asks to provide the answer, which is actually encouraged at Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a related question [PHPMyadmin does not show mysql error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735924/phpmyadmin-does-not-show-mysql-error-messages). I will state that I do not understand how to solve the problem with this answer. I did note that @anomie states:

> If mysql_error works, it seems more likely that the problem is in phpMyAdmin's character set conversion function `PMA_DBI_convert_message` in libraries/database_interface.lib.php

I found this section in libraries/database_interface.lib.php which sets the encoding:

```
function PMA_DBI_convert_message($message)
{
    // latin always last!
    $encodings = array(
        'japanese'      => 'EUC-JP', //'ujis',
        'japanese-sjis' => 'Shift-JIS', //'sjis',
        'korean'        => 'EUC-KR', //'euckr',
        'russian'       => 'KOI8-R', //'koi8r',
        'ukrainian'     => 'KOI8-U', //'koi8u',
        'greek'         => 'ISO-8859-7', //'greek',
        'serbian'       => 'CP1250', //'cp1250',
        'estonian'      => 'ISO-8859-13', //'latin7',
        'slovak'        => 'ISO-8859-2', //'latin2',
        'czech'         => 'ISO-8859-2', //'latin2',
        'hungarian'     => 'ISO-8859-2', //'latin2',
        'polish'        => 'ISO-8859-2', //'latin2',
        'romanian'      => 'ISO-8859-2', //'latin2',
        'spanish'       => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'swedish'       => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'italian'       => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'norwegian-ny'  => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'norwegian'     => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'portuguese'    => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'danish'        => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'dutch'         => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'english'       => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'french'        => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
        'german'        => 'CP1252', //'latin1',
    );
```

I changed the line for English to `'english'     => 'UTF-8',` which now correctly displays the full error description.

I'm not sure if there are other encoding issues which may cause other functions to lose text, but this at least solves my problem.